# how to deploy asp.net Core 3.1 to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-deployment

I have a small ASP.NET Core 3.1 console app, which I want to deploy to Azure.
When I run this deploy command:

`git push azure master`

I get the following output:

```
........

........

remote: Running deployment command...
remote: Handling .NET Console Application deployment with dotnet.exe.
remote: D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.2.109\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1. [D:\home\site\repository\ConsoleApp.csproj]
remote: Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet restore "D:\home\site\repository\ServiceBusWriter.sln"
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote:
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.
To https://ServicebusToSQL.scm.azurewebsites.net/ServicebusToSQL.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

From this output I'm gathering, that the remote Azure deployment environment must (obviously) also be .NET Core 3.1

What are the proper commends or actions, which will force Azure remote to be .NET Core 3.1 ?

Comment: Are you using docker? can you share which image are you using?

Comment: Not using docker yet. Just trying to deploy as  a web app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure app service doesn't support .NET Core 3.1 out of the box in all regions. So if you want to use .NET Core 3.1, you need to enable the .NET Core 3.1 SDK extensions.

Or you need to move your app to .NET Core 3.1 supported region. You can get details about the .NET Core support in Azure App service - https://aspnetcoreon.azurewebsites.net/

Or you need to create your app using Web App from Docker - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/containers/

Comment: or use a supported region ;) or web app + docker

Comment: @4c74356b41 Modified my answer :)